# Microsoft Edge API and IE Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I like to open links from a [sidebar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/sidebar) inside a normal tab. This works in general but I am not able to open the tab content in IE mode of edge browser.

If I click a link in the sidebar:

- the tab content shall be loaded in IE mode (because we use an old intranet application),
- the tab content is always loaded in edge mode,
- it is not possible to change the mode of the tab (no action, if clicked the menu item or icon),
- it has no effect, if the address is in the edge property list for IE mode pages,
- if the same page load direct in a new tab (from address bar, not from sidebar) anything works as expected.

Do there exist any API property, call etc. / manifest property to activate the IE mode from the add-on js code? Do there exist any other solution to change the mode?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Supported APIs for Microsoft Edge extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support), there is no API to activate the IE mode from extension. If you want a link to be opened in IE mode, you could [Configure IE mode Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies). Based on my research, there is no option to load a page in IE mode inside the sidebar. You need to select "open link in a new tab" and load it in IE mode.